# Assert Web API Method is returning a specific type?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a Web API 2.0 project with the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<Fruit> Get()
{
    // get list of fruit
    var listOfFruit = GetFruitsFromService();

    // return list of fruit
    return listOfFruit;
}
```

I then have a Unit Test like so:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Get_Should_Bring_Back_List_Of_Fruit()
{
    // set
    var controller = new FruitController();
    var listOfFruits = new List<FruitRM>();
    // act
    var result = controller.Get() as IList<FruitRM>;
    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(listOfFruits, result);
}
```

That test is failing. How do I test that the Web API action returns a list of `FruitRM`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not checking the type, you are checking if one instance of a list equals something else (possibly *another* instance to an empty list). This will never be true.

If you want to check the type, check the type:

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(IList<FruitRM>));
```

Note: You seem to check on implementing another interface than the return type. I wouldn't do that. The method should return an `IEnumerable<Fruit>`. If it should return a `IList<Fruit>`, change the return type, not your unit test.

Comment: Thank you, that worked and I also implemented your tip about `IList<T>`.